# Prove that $ES_0$ has the Fatou property.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define
$$ES_0(X)=\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R} : P(X+c\geq 0)=1\}.$$
$ES_0(X)$ has the Fatou property if for any bounded sequence $(X_n)_n$ which converges
$P$-a.s. to some $X$,
$$ES_0(X)\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}ES_0(X_n).$$
Let $M:=\liminf_{n\to\infty} ES_0(X_n)$, my idea is to prove that $M+\epsilon\in\{c\in\mathbb{R} : P(X+c\geq 0)=1\}$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

By definition
$ES_0(X_n)=\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R} : P(X_n+c\geq 0)=1\},$
so we can say
$$P(X_n+ES_0(X_n)+\epsilon\geq 0)=1 \quad \text{for every } \epsilon>0,$$
thus, by Fatou's Lemma,
$$P(X+M+\epsilon\geq 0)\leq 1 \quad \text{for every } \epsilon>0.$$
Now I don't know how to prove that this is actually an equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a an increasing sequence of integers $(n_k)$ such that $M=\lim_{k\to\infty}ES_0(X_{n_k})$. Then for each positive $\varepsilon$,
$$
1=\mathbb P\left(X_{n_k}+ES_0(X_{n_k})+\varepsilon\geqslant 0\right)
\leqslant \mathbb P\left(X+M+\varepsilon/2\geqslant 0\right)+
\mathbb P\left(X_{n_k}-X+ES_0(X_{n_k})-M+\varepsilon/2\geqslant 0\right)
$$
and $\mathbb P\left(X_{n_k}-X+ES_0(X_{n_k})-M+\varepsilon/2\geqslant 0\right)$ goes to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity.

Comment: If $M=\lim_{k\to\infty}ES_0(X_{n_k})$, then can't I say that for every $\varepsilon>0$, 
$$
1=\mathbb P\left(X_{n_k}+ES_0(X_{n_k})+\varepsilon\geq 0\right)= \mathbb P\left(X+M+\varepsilon\geqslant 0\right)?$$

Comment: @MathLover If you can justify that the two probabilities are equal, yes, but I do not see why.

Comment: $1=\mathbb P\left(X_{n_k}+ES_0(X_{n_k})+\varepsilon\geq 0\right)=\mathbb{E}[1_{(X_{n_k}+ES_0(X_{n_k})+\varepsilon\geq 0)}]$ and then I would apply the dominated convergence theorem. Is this argument wrong?

Comment: You apply a convergence theorem, the limit is not equal in general to a term of the sequence so some extra argument is needed.